# В чем разница между TStrings и string?

Tags: delphi

При работе с ListBox получаю ошибку

> [Pascal Error] Unit2.pas(102): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TStrings'

А я всего-лишь хочу сверить данные из файла, с выбранным элементом.

```
if ListBox1.items=otv1 then
```

Как делать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

**String** - это просто строка.
**TStrings** - коллекция строк, которые находятся в ListBox1.

Если Вам нужно сверить выбранную строку с OTV1, то нужно писать так:

```
  if (ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex] = otv1) then
       ......
```

**ListBox1.ItemIndex** - номер выбранной строки.

Насколько я понял из Вашего вопроса, Вы пишете, что-то на подобии тестирующей программы (проверка правильного ответа). Тогда я бы порекомендовал Вам использовать **ComboBox** вместо **ListBox**.

Comment: А какая разница кроме размера?

Comment: @dex
А какая разница кроме размера?


удобней и во большинстве программ так.

Comment: Если говорить про удобство то тогда уже группа RadioButton

Comment: Хм, а чем удобнее? Меня это интересует. Работают они одинаково по сути, т.е. для программиста одно и то же, а для пользователя чем же?